# NextJS PWA Service worker map 404 in Production

Tags: progressive-web-apps, next.js

I am trying to build a PWA with NextJS and this https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-pwa

It have been working fine in development, but know i try to build and run it in production.

It seems like the files below only is being build when i run it as dev and is thereby missing in the prod build.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMO9O.png)

Is this an error in my config?

```js
module.exports = withImages(
  withPWA({
    pwa: {
      dest: 'public'
    },
    env: {
      apiUrl: process.env.API_URL
    },
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      if (!isServer) {
        config.node = {
          fs: 'empty'
        }
      }

      return config
    }
  })
)
```

Please help!

Comment: Is sw.js and workbox-*.js are generated in /public folder ?